# jQuery iterate through array of objects recursively and return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion

I have the following json which represents pages on a site which have sub pages via an items array, which currently comprises 2 top level items - about and services:

```
var data = '[{"id":107,"name":"About Us","route":"page","slug":"about","parent":0,"module":1,"items":[{"id":118,"name":"About Sub Page","route":"page","slug":"about-sub-page","parent":107,"items":[]}]},{"id":129,"name":"Services","route":"page","slug":"services","parent":0,"module":1,"items":[{"id":174,"name":"Services sub page","route":"page","slug":"services-sub-page","parent":129,"items":[]}]}]';
```

I am trying to write a function which iterates recursively over the array of objects (data = JSON.parse(data)) and identify the index of the top level items. For instance, in my function if I use the 'about' slug, it will return 0, as will 'about-sub-page'. Similarly, 'services-sub-page' would return 1.

I have this at the moment:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);

function check(slug,data) {
 var result;
 $.each(data, function(index){
  if (this.slug === slug) {
    result = index;
    return false;
  }
  else {
   check(slug,this.items);
  }
 });
   return result;
 }
```

This works fine if I pass a top level slug eg

```
 var index = check('about',data);
 console.log(index); // returns 0

 var index = check('services',data);
 console.log(index); // returns 1
```

However, if I try with a sub page I get undefined

```
 var index = check('services-sub-page',data);
 console.log(index); // returns undefined
```

I believe I need to return false to break out of the each loop, but not sure why it's not working when I try and use the function recursively.

Comment: You should do `result = check(slug, this.items);`, because otherwise you are definitely returning undefined when it falls to a subitem (where that else clause gets hit).

Comment: Hi James, tried this - still getting undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because this stops iterating if a condition is met.

```js
var data = '[{"id":107,"name":"About Us","route":"page","slug":"about","parent":0,"module":1,"items":[{"id":118,"name":"About Sub Page","route":"page","slug":"about-sub-page","parent":107,"items":[]}]},{"id":129,"name":"Services","route":"page","slug":"services","parent":0,"module":1,"items":[{"id":174,"name":"Services sub page","route":"page","slug":"services-sub-page","parent":129,"items":[]}]}]';

function check(slug, data) {
    function iter(a, i) {
        if (a.slug === slug || Array.isArray(a.items) && a.items.some(iter)) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index,
        array = JSON.parse(data);

    array.some(iter)
    return index;
}

document.write(check('about', data) + '<br>');
document.write(check('services', data) + '<br>');
document.write(check('services-sub-page', data) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

data = JSON.parse(data);

function check(slug,data) {

var result;

$.each(data, function(index){

if (this.slug === slug) {

```
result = index;

return false;
```

}

else {

result = check(slug,this.items); // assign to result variable

}

});

return result;

}

Comment: Just assign check(slug,this.items);to result variable

Comment: Hi Sams (and James) - have implemented this, but still getting undefined?